# Python: errno2 no such file or directory in google colab

Tags: python, django, google-colaboratory

pip install django

!django-admin startproject PyShop

!python manage.py runserver

----:In the last line of code, I should be getting some kind of a web link as an output but i get this location error. Is there any syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't in PyShop directory. Use:

```
!python PyShop/manage.py runserver
```

**Note!** I'm not sure that you can open this link to the application

Comment: ok i am getting the web link but what is this?
You have 18 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

Comment: @SantoshDeori honestly, I didn't run any web project like django or flask in google colab and I'm not sure that it can work. So I answered your question (why your command doesn't work), but I don't know what do you need to do next...